# how to generate PDF/A-1a pdf in PHP?

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using the `mPDF` library. It is generating PDFs in the PDF/A-1b format. But I want to generate PDF/A-1a pdf format. 
How can I do this?

with `$this->PDFA = true;` option I can generate PDF/A-1b format. What do I have to do for PDF/A-1a ?

Comment: It doesn't seem that mPDF is able to create PDF/A-1a compliant documents. Only PDF/X-1a and PDF/A1-b are supported as far as i can tell reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to mPDF manual, while `$this->PDFA` is set to **true** then compliance with **PDF/A-1b** specification is forced. What happens if you set it to false?

Comment: Not very helpful: he is already using $this->PDFA = true  and A-1b compliance, but he wants A-1a compliance (whatever that means).